# Hot Reloading is Not Working in Jhipster

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

I  am working on Jhipster Project.I get latet version 0.8.2.But i getting problem in hot reloading.If i changed some code in java file then no reloading is run .Please help me.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on Jhipster's website (section 2.2 in the Using Jhipster in development section).

Comment: No... and I have one more question is HotReloading will work on prod Profile or localhost:8080 Url or Grunt Url 127.0.0.1:9000

Comment: Well first of all, you should follow those instructions for enabling hot reloading.  It doesn't work out of the box.  It will work against the running instance of your application that you enable hot reloading on, which would likely be localhost:8080 in your case.  It won't work against the "grunt serve" instance because that's just a NodeJS process running, so it doesn't know anything about your running Spring application.

Comment: can you help me step hot reloading in STS Please.

Answer (score 0):

Hot Relod doesnt work on java. If you change the code in your Spring Application, you need to run your gradle again.

However using yarn run or npm start you can enable hot relod on the frontend which is proxyed on another port.

Hope this helps.